# Word for "this is an example of the type of incident being discussed"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Here's an example context:

> Recently, there has been a lot of discussion about stores overpricing their bacon. The recent event in which the store priced bacon at $100/lb is a perfect ___ of this.

I was using the word "Example" at the blank there, but I vaguely recall there being a more suitable word. Example doesn't seem quite right, since it would technically mean an example of the discussion, right?

Comment: You need to include synonyms and near-synonyms of 'example / instance / occasioning // case ...', though I think the potential ambiguity persists. Note that you need a different example yourself, though, as 'example' here _must_ refer back to the overpricing: a store overpricing bacon may be an example of bacon overpricing in general, but not of discussion.

Comment: A perfect example is an epitome or an embodiment. That said, the blank will continue to refer to either *discussion* or *overpricing* no matter what you put in there. To make it impossible for it to refer to *discussion* you will have to change the sentence.

Comment: Yes, agree a perfect case or overpricing sounds very slightly strange. I like the 'instance' suggestion or maybe 'a perfect illustration of this'. You could add Ibf and Jelila's answer and get 'a perfect case in point' .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case**

Case means ‘example of a situation occurring’, or ‘situation’.

Example:

- Recently, there has been a lot of discussion about stores overpricing their bacon. The recent event in which the store priced bacon at $100/lb is a perfect case of such overpricing.
- In the case of a fire occurring, meet at the designated area.
- She had thought he was honest, but sadly that was not the case.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20case

Note: in the example taken from the question, I have added the word ‘overpricing’ to make it clear that the ‘case’ applies to ‘the price’ and not to ‘the discussion’. I added the word ‘such’ to denote that the overpricing was an example of overpricing of the type being discussed.

Answer (score 0):

a **point**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/point)

> The major idea or essential part of a concept or narrative: You have
>   missed the whole point of the novel. A significant, outstanding, or
>   effective idea, argument, or suggestion

As in your example:

*The recent event in which the store priced bacon at $100/lb is a perfect **point** of this.*